# Left margin in SQL query two column string concatenation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following SQL query result in this format

```
1     Cash in Hand
1040    Saving Account
1050    Student fee Account 1050
```

I want to this query result in following format

```
1       Cash in Hand
1040    Saving Account
1050    Student fee Account 1050
```

It is not that it is one column having result of two columns being concatenated.

I have tried this query but problem is still exist

```
SELECT     
   CAST(AccountNo as char(10)) + ' ' + AccountName As AccountName,AccountNo
FROM         
   ChartOfAccounts
```

Comment: Cast is actually working, but you need fixed-width font.

Comment: how can do the fixed-width font

Comment: This is not Sql, but presentation problem. You should show data in columns, but if you cannot (a ComboBox, perhaps?), you might set font to Courier New or any other font in which all the characters are of equal width - ie. space is as wide as `w`.

Comment: thank you for help me. I try your seggession. so I solved my problem can you give me list of fonts having equal character width. why are you not give me answer in as answer i can accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT AccountNo + REPLICATE(' ', 10 - DATALENGTH(AccountNo)) + AccountName as AccountName
FROM ChartOfAccounts
```

Comment: but it is giving following error `Must declare the scalar variable "@AccountNo".
`

Comment: no following error occuring `Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Cash in Hand' to data type int` i try to this `cast(AccountNo + REPLICATE(' ', 10 - DATALENGTH(AccountNo)) As char) + AccountName as AccountName`. error remove but my problum was not solved.